# Material3 checkbox android cannot customize button

Tags: android, material3

How to customize checkbox's button in material3 android? I've tried this :

```
//ic_checkbox.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_off_enabled"
        android:state_checked="false" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_enabled2"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_off_enabled" />
</selector>

//activity_main.xml
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkRememberMe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:button="@drawable/ic_checkbox" />
```

checkbox_on_enabled2 :
[image]

checkbox_off_enabled :
[image]

but the result is I got blank checkbox :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this answer come late, but I just had the same problem, so I'm still going to answer in case anybody sees this. My custom button style could not be set when I used `CheckBox` or `MaterialCheckBox`.

To make it work, simply use a `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox` like such :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector" />
```

With my `checkbox_selector` being :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/new_checkbox" android:state_checked="false" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/new_checkbox_selected" android:state_checked="true" />

</selector>
```

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use theme
`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` attribute on your MaterialCheckBox.

Answer (score -2):

`CheckBox` definitely isn't part of Material Design Components.

Instead use `MaterialCheckBox`; for example:

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@{ selected }"/>
```

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: "does not work" is not an error description, but a complaint.

Comment: i've described the error in the post. i need solution

Comment: This part is just nonsensical: `android:button="@drawable/ic_checkbox"`. Why you even use Material Design, when then starting to paint your own check-boxes?